# Spring not using mongo custom converters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mongo

I have been trying to register my own write custom converters to change the default ID value.
But it never actually calls.
Here is my Custom Converter

```
public class EventKeyConverter implements Converter<Event,DBObject> {

    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Event object) {
        DBObject dbObject = DBObjectTransformer.toDBObject(object);
        dbObject.put("_id", KeyGenerator.getRandomKey());
        return dbObject;
    }

}
```

here is the place that I did register customer converter

```
@Override
@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
    converters.add(new EventKeyConverter());
    return new CustomConversions(converters);
}

@Override
@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(
            eventsMongoDbFactory(), mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate eventsMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    final MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(
            eventsMongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
    template.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);

    return template;
}
```

When I'm saving some objects this converter never gets called.

**Edit 1** :
I need to change the default object Id into some custom Id (UUID + random key) in all repositories. That why I tried to use mongo converter.

**Edit 2 :**
Just found the issue. Change @Configuration to @Component in class that contains customConversion() and it works fine. But still wondering what is happened here ?

Comment: Could you please show how you actually save the objects? I mean, why would you need to convert a POJO to actual BSON to save it to DB?

Comment: I need to change the default object Id into some custom Id (UUID + random key) in all repositories. That why I tried to use mongo converter.

Comment: Rajith, in mongodb you are not allowed to update the _id fields. If you would like to add new objects with a custom _id, you should provide the needed field with the @Id annotation and when you insert an object manually set the _id.

Comment: just want to do same thing like this .. http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e2670

Comment: Works for me - I put the @Component tag and now Spring uses my convertors

Answer (score 2):

`@Configuration` defines a Spring context fragment that contains methods that if annotated with `@Bean` return new beans and put them in the context.

`@Component` is a way of saying "this Pojo is a Spring bean". You then need a `@ComponentScan` annotation or XML equivalent to scan packages for `@Component` annotated beans.

So in your case, you created the converter fine, but it wasn't registered as a Spring bean until you added the `@Component`, so it didn't work initially.