# custom converters not registered in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, converters

I'm new to Spring Boot. In my Controller I'm using `UUID`s as `@PathVariable`. By default spring returns `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` when passing an invalid `UUID`.

When the client passes an invalid `UUID` I want to throw a custom `InvalidUUIDException`, so that I'm able to return a customized ErrorDto using this Exception.

To archieve that I'm trying to register a custom `UUIDConverter` (implementing `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`).

```
@Component
public class UUIDConverter implements Converter<String, UUID>
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}");

    @Override
    public UUID convert(String input) throws InvalidUuidException
    {
        if (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
            throw new InvalidUuidException(input);
        }

        return UUID.fromString(input);
    }
}
```

To register this component, I'm adding this Converter to springs `ConversionService`. Using the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService()
    {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        bean.setConverters(getConverters());

        return bean;
    }

    private Set<Converter> getConverters()
    {
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
        converters.add(new UUIDConverter());

        return converters;
    }
}
```

I've tried also to use `@Component` instead of `@Configuration` as it was mentioned here: [Spring not using mongo custom converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930933/spring-not-using-mongo-custom-converters)

Other solutions I tried out: Naming the bean `conversionServiceFactoryBean` instead of `conversionService`. Or calling `bean.afterPropertiesSet()` and retuning a `ConversionService` using `bean.getObject()` ...

I've also tried to extend from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, overriding `addFormatters` and add my converter there using `addConverter`...

As mentioned here: [How to register custom converters in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239585/how-to-register-custom-converters-in-spring-boot) I've also tried to register the converter as a `@Bean` directly.

It does not matter what I tried out, the `UUIDConverter` will not be applied.

What is the correct solution do something like that in spring-boot?
Can anyone help here? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue

Comment: do you have SprinbWebMvc enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I only know about this issue because I've done the same myself with another class and spent hours debugging...

The `UUIDConverter` is a bean [already a registered by Spring itself](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/util/UUIDConverter.html). Choose literally any other name and you should see it appear.

Comment: Huh, need to try that out. In that case I'd expect NoUniqueBean exception or something similar :/ Thanks for your hint!